# Свой API на Yii2 что работает не так, где ошибка ?

Tags: json, yii2, api

**Здравствуйте.**

Вот мой репозиторий - https://github.com/definaru/api

Он рабочий.

---

Проблемки следующие:
1) Не могу сделать выборку из БД вот так:
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/

У меня получается всё в одну кучу, в одну строку.

2) При получении на другом сайте не могу получить конкретные данные. Выявил синтаксическую ошибку, полагаю что мой массив обёрнут в HTML.

Если создать json файл и поместить то, что я получаю с другого сайта, то всё работает, я получаю любые данные какие захочу.
Но смысл API в том чтобы орудовать данными сразу а не вести танцы с бубном.

Подскажите как это реализовать? Что я не так сделал?

Comment: 1. Как именно "так"? Вероятно, вы имеет в виду отформатированные данные? Если да, то все дело в том, что сервер должен помимо того, что отдавать сами данные в формате json, так еще и передавать заголовок `application/json`.
2. Какую именно ошибку вы получаете? Как вы поняли, что массив обернут в HTML?
3. Судя по всему, вам нужна такая конструкция `echo json_encode($array);` с установкой упомянутого выше заголовка.

Comment: @VenZell, я надеюсь, что вы поняли, что я делаю это на фреймворке Yii2
Так вот, если вы смотрели мой репозиторий, то видели что я там закомментировал
\Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
Эта конструкция по идее как-то преобразует в json
на странице результата, через F12 - я открыл инспектор кода, и увидел что мой массив сидит в обёртке <body>.
С помощью "json_last_error_msg" я определил синтаксическую ошибку.
JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX
Все настройки здесь https://github.com/definaru/api/blob/master/frontend/api/controllers/PageController.php

Comment: @VenZell https://github.com/definaru/api/blob/master/frontend/api/views/page/index.php
Строка 3. Класс Html делает тоже самое что вы предложили сделать в своём пункте 3.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы API работало как я хотел, через json
Надо в Yii2 в контроллере сделать соответствующий заголовок:

```
public function actionIndex($id = '')
{
    $json = Catalog::find()->asArray()->where(['id' => $id])->one();
    $response = Yii::$app->response;
    $response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $response->data = $json;
    return $response->data;
}
```

в представление ничего писать не нужно, то есть вьюшку можно оставить пустой.
Что касаемо формирования выдачи результата в столбик, я пока решения не нашёл, но основная задача заключалась в том, чтобы данные приходили.
Это рабочий код. Протестировано.

Comment: Зачем вы список элементов добавляете в `data` и потом возвращаете её же? Либо оставьте только `return $json;` или ничего не возвращайте, так как response в любом случае будет отдан браузеру после завершения работы действия

Comment: @edvardpotter - я делал по документации Yii
Как я понял $json - это полученный массив данных из БД.
А Yii::$app->response->data - это обработанный и отформатированный массив в json формате.
Если проверить оба массива - они отличаются.
В любом случае я прислушаюсь к вашей рекомендации, если она будет рабочей. :)

Comment: Нет, это работает немного иначе: если вы указываете формат ответа JSON, то любые данные которые вы возвращаете в методе экшена(используя языковую конструкцию `return`) будут сериализованы в JSON. Если же передаёте данные в `response->data` то возвращать ничего не нужно.